# Python function to print datetime of elements in a list

Tags: python, function, datetime

I'm trying to define a function that takes a datetime string and a list of time zones to print out in a specific format the datetime of each timezone in the list but Im confused, how can I achieve this??

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

formato = "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M"
x = dt.datetime.now()
y = ["Africa/Bangui", "America/Chile", "Asia/Calcutta"]


def func (x, y):
  fecha = x.strftime(formato)

  for i in y:
    zona = pytz.timezone(y[i])
    print(zona)

  
func(x,y)
```

Comment: `America/Chile` is wrong timezone, please refer to this for correct timezone, https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping through elements of `y` not index of `y`. And there is no time zone - `America/Chile`.

For Chile, use `Chile/Continental` or `Chile/EasterIsland`

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

formato = "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M"
x = dt.datetime.now()
y = ["Africa/Bangui", "Chile/Continental", "Asia/Calcutta"]


def func (x, y):

  for i in y:
    zona = pytz.timezone(i)
    print(x.astimezone(zona).strftime(formato))

  
func(x,y)
```

Output:

```
25/07/2020, 06:09
25/07/2020, 01:09
25/07/2020, 10:39
```

Comment: What is `fecha` used for?

Comment: @Pynchia It was there in OP's code. Hence, I kept it as it is. It's doing nothing. Removed it